# Find pairs in two columns table and join into three columns table

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, group-by

I'm trying to figure out solution for the following, I need to find pairs employee > manager and print it out.

The given table is:

```
employee            manager
----------------------------------
Bryce Posada        Antony Real  
Sung Hosey          Aurelio Havlik  
Joan Strother       Aurelio Havlik  
Irwin Fulks         Barton Rose  
Rocco Keplin        Benito Cowboy  
Efrain Ricketson    Benito Cowboy  
Patricia Hackenberg Benito Cowboy  
Paris Sigala        Chuck Lawson  
Alva Kaul           Ernest Divens  
Eli Bielecki        Ernest Divens  
Walton Virden       Ernest Divens  
Raphael Montesino   Ernest Divens  
Dewayne Biggs       Lonny Meller  
Josef Bakken        Marc Margulies  
Everett Gresham     Marc Margulies  
Zachariah Yochum    Otto Brannum
```

Now, I need to get the results as follows, for example:

- Anthony Real manages only one person, so there will be null as a
  pair.
- Aurelio Havlik manages two people, so there will be pair.
- Benito Cowboy manages three people, so there will be one pair and one
  record with null.

See below:

```
employee_paired1        employee_paired2    manager
---------------------------------------------------------
Bryce Posada            null                Antony Real  
Sung Hosey              Joan Strother       Aurelio Havlik  
Irwin Fulks             null                Barton Rose  
Rocco Keplin            Efrain Ricketson    Benito Cowboy  
Patricia Hackenberg     null                Benito Cowboy  
Paris Sigala            null                Chuck Lawson  
Alva Kaul               Eli Bielecki        Ernest Divens  
Walton Virden           Raphael Montesino   Ernest Divens  
Dewayne Biggs           Dewayne Biggs       Lonny Meller  
Josef Bakken            Everett Gresham     Marc Margulies  
Zachariah Yochum        Zachariah Yochum    Otto Brannum
```

So far my code generates results but they overlap...

Edit: As per request I'm adding [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d0082/1)

And sample code to comply with rules of this forum:

```
select * from ( 
select max(c1.employee) employee1, c2.employee employee2, c1.manager creator from test3 c1
join test3 c2 on c1.manager = c2.manager
and c1.employee < c2.employee
) a
```

Comment: Does the table have any `ID` column? On what basis do you decide if two employees are paired up and who is left alone in case of a manager managing 3 people? In case of two people, who is paired1 vs paired2?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @clinomaniac, the table doesn't have an ID. There is no rule to who should be left with null. In case of two people, there is no rule who should be paired with who. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Strawberry, this is maximum description I can give, nothing's been omitted. I read the like provided, thanks.

Comment: Bye then. Good luck.

Comment: @Strawberry, I spent 30 minutes getting around to write it as best I could, sorry if my answer sounded as I would not care, in contrary, I'm trying to solve this for hours now, SQL is not really my thing and I'm really tired now. Thanks anyways

Comment: @QB1979 From the link Strawberry mentioned, you just have #2. Can you include #1 and 3?

Comment: Why is dewayne biggs paired with himself in your results as is Zachariah Yochum?  I would expect the 2nd column to be null in both cases like in Bryce Posada

Comment: @xQbert, it is an error indeed, sorry about that.

Comment: @Strawberry, I added missing parts, the SQL Fiddle with DB schema and my lousy attempt to extract data. Thanks!

Comment: @clinomaniac, added description as per your comment - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo on Rextester](http://rextester.com/RNI13649)

I'm assuming your sample data is flawed:
I would not expect to see Dewayne Biggs nor Zachariah Yochum paired with themselves.

```
employee_paired1        employee_paired2    manager
---------------------------------------------------------
Dewayne Biggs           Dewayne Biggs       Lonny Meller  
Zachariah Yochum        Zachariah Yochum    Otto Brannum
```

I'm also assuming the order of the pairings and who is in pair1 and who is not doesn't matter.  So I used the approach of simply sorting by the employee column and thus the one with the last name alphabetically will always be the odd man out and the one with the earliest alphabetic name will always be the first one in pair1.

A little tricky... but using user variables (the @MGR, @RN below) to simulate row_number functionality including partitioning of data; and function `mod()` we can generate two sets of data one for the first column Der_tab_col1 and one for second column.  We use `Mod()` to limit the data in the first column to only contain odd row numbers  we left outer join this to the second set of data containing even row numbers per manager and only include those records matching on manager and when the row number is 1 greater thus the even number if one exists.  This logic is visible in the demo as I included the RN fields for both the derived table 1 and derived table 2.  Each derived table (der_tab_Col1, Der_tab_col2) is using the same order by and being executed against the same base dataset ensuring we obtain the Same order and results in each query).

```
SELECT Der_tab_Col1.employee as employee_paired1        
     , Der_tab_Col2.employee as employee_paired2    
     , Der_tab_Col1.manager
FROM (SELECT A.Employee
           , case when @MGR <> A.Manager THEN @RN:=0 end as resetRN
           , @RN:=@RN+1  RN
           , @MGR:=A.Manager as Manager
      FROM SO48874377 A
      CROSS JOIN (Select @RN:=0, @MGR:='') Z
      ORDER BY manager, employee) Der_tab_Col1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.Employee
                , case when @MGR2 <> A.Manager THEN @RN2:=0 end as resetRN
                , @RN2:=@RN2+1  RN
                , @MGR2:=A.Manager as Manager
      FROM SO48874377 A
      CROSS JOIN (Select @RN2:=0, @MGR2:='') Z
      ORDER BY manager, employee) Der_Tab_col2
   on Der_tab_Col1.Manager = Der_tab_Col2.Manager
  and Der_tab_Col1.RN+1 = Der_tab_Col2.RN
WHERE mod(der_tab_col1.rn,2)=1
ORDER BY der_tab_col1.manager, Der_tab_Col1.RN;
```

Giving us:

```
+----+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|    | employee_paired1  | employee_paired2    |    manager     |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|  1 | Bryce Posada      | NULL                | Antony Real    |
|  2 | Joan Strother     | Sung Hosey          | Aurelio Havlik |
|  3 | Irwin Fulks       | NULL                | Barton Rose    |
|  4 | Efrain Ricketson  | Patricia Hackenberg | Benito Cowboy  |
|  5 | Rocco Keplin      | NULL                | Benito Cowboy  |
|  6 | Paris Sigala      | NULL                | Chuck Lawson   |
|  7 | Alva Kaul         | Eli Bielecki        | Ernest Divens  |
|  8 | Raphael Montesino | Walton Virden       | Ernest Divens  |
|  9 | Dewayne Biggs     | NULL                | Lonny Meller   |
| 10 | Everett Gresham   | Josef Bakken        | Marc Margulies |
| 11 | Zachariah Yochum  | NULL                | Otto Brannum   |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

The SQL where clause `mod(der_tab_col1.rn,2)` simply means divide the RN (row number) by 2 if there is a remainder then it is odd, and we want those. If it's even then we don't want those as the even numbered rows would be in column 2.

One can see the power of analytical functions even in simulated means using this approach.

Note: we could continue the concept of left joins and user variables  and use mod 3 instead of 2 if we wanted 3 paired names instead of 2; so a pattern for expansion is defined here as well.